# How to pass multi-dimentional array from android to soap web service parameter

Tags: php, android, arraylist, multidimensional-array, ksoap2

I have a problem with multi-dimensional array , I have web service in soap and need to pass this array as parameter like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> phone = new HashMap<String, String>();

    phone.put("internalId", "phone");
    phone.put("fieldId", "8");
    phone.put("displayName", "Phone");
    phone.put("value", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
    custom_field.add(phone);
    /*Log.d("hash Phone", String.valueOf(phone));
    Log.d("hash Phone custom Field ", String.valueOf(custom_field));*/

HashMap<String, String> address = new HashMap<String, String>();

    address.put("internalId", "address");
    address.put("fieldId", "3");
    address.put("displayName", "Address");
    address.put("value", " XXXX XXXXX, XXXX");
    custom_field.add(address);
    /*Log.d("hash Address", String.valueOf(phone));
    Log.d("hash Address custom Field ", String.valueOf(custom_field));*/
HashMap<String, String> nationalid = new HashMap<String, String>();

    nationalid.put("internalId", "nationalid");
    nationalid.put("fieldId", "13");
    nationalid.put("displayName", "National-ID");
    nationalid.put("value", "XXXXXXX");
        custom_field.add(nationalid);

HashMap<String, String> maritalstatus = new HashMap<String, String>();

    maritalstatus.put("internalId", "maritalstatus");
    maritalstatus.put("fieldId", "16");
    maritalstatus.put("displayName", "Marital status");
    maritalstatus.put("value", "Single");

    custom_field.add(maritalstatus);
```

I want to pass array like this sample PHP array as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [internalId] => phone
            [fieldId] => 8
            [displayName] => Phone
            [value] => XXXXXXXXX
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [internalId] => address
            [fieldId] => 3
            [displayName] => Address
            [value] =>  XXXX XXXXX, XXXX
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [internalId] => nationalid
            [fieldId] => 13
            [displayName] => National-ID
            [value] => XXXXXXX
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [internalId] => maritalstatus
            [fieldId] => 16
            [displayName] => Marital status
            [value] => Single
        )

)
```

and getting soapfault error as an error like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize:
```

Any help how can I get this done via android.

I have tried hashmap nesting as well as arraylist nesting, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: create a loop and add each element of array into the request object. it should work.

Comment: another approach is marshalling, try this link https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#sending/receiving_array_of_complex_types_or_primitives

Comment: @niravshah_php now I have another way to accomplish this so i am  close this issue, thanks for your efforts.